# Does cable for a 30A circuit between garage studs need shielding?

Tags: wiring, receptacle, garage

I am trying to add a 30 amp service for my garage-parked RV.  I have plenty of open slots in the electrical panel (which is mounted midway on the wall in my garage) and the plan was to do a 2.5 foot run straight below to a single 30amp plug.  Do I need to shield the cable if it is inside the wall or will a simple hang between the studs suffice?  The garage is prefinished so I was hoping to just make a hole for the after build box and run the cable straight up.  Thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: "Thoughts or suggestions" questions are usually too broad here. I've revised your title to be more specific. Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: "After build box"? Does that mean you have drywall or some other interior sheathing?

Comment: I answered or started prior to the edit is this a finished wall that will be cut? If so the cable will need to be covered.

Answer (score 1):

Code requires the cable through the studs below 8’ to be covered.

In the past we have cut a sheet of Sheetrock in strips to cover the Romex (what we used). Plywood would have been better but on these jobs the owner wanted CHEEP!

4 strips per sheet attached was all it took to pass inspections no cap on the top but I have heard of a cap being required.

Code only states 1/2” Sheetrock or plywood not the entire wall, we also did the same above and below the service panel as required.

Comment: If the hole is along the stud yes by code it needs to be covered.

Comment: That is ugly. I don't know how you put up with customers like that. I guess their house their rules.

Comment: It may be ugly but many homes prior to the requirement had nothing in the garages and this was in the late 70’s when those homes were 1/2 million don’t know what what they are worth today but many times more ugly or not it met code

Answer (score 1):

The plain cable should be okay inside the wall, the mounting/attachment requirements should be waive inside a finish wall. you don't need to attach to wall. This is for the cable.

I believe any plugs in a garage need to have GFCI protection, probably a breaker type, since I don't know if they have 30 amp GFCI plugs/receptacles.

Conduit is extra protection, since mice/rats don't usually eat conduit.  They do like cables.